# Package Beans does not Exist

Tags: java, netbeans

I am a .NET developer dabbling into the JSP world.  I loaded NetBeans 6.5.1 and get an error in this page:

```
<%@page import="java.io" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                      "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">;
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>JSP Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Hello World!</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

the error is:

```
"Package Beans does not Exist"
```

I should add that I created a new Java Web Application and then copy-and-pasted some code that called for the above import. then I get the error.

Help with this error would be great along with any tutorials or books.

Comment: I suspect the error lies somewhere other than the above JSP snippet. Is there any other code in the project yet?

Comment: @dnndeveloper: You should edit changes into your question.  I edited the above into your question.

Comment: awesome, thank you - I will keep that in mind for my next post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with the classpath.  Your configuration of the server, plus setup in the WAR file, should be checked against a working one.